# Battlefield 3 installer problem

Tags: battlefield-3, origin

I just bought BF3 for my PC. I just upgraded it to a gaming PC, using win7. Trying to install the game I keep getting this message and can't go any further:

> "The game installation directory is invalid. Please select a different directory."

I Read your answer. Opened the file that's shown:

```
<Setting key="DownloadInPlaceDir" type="10" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games"/>
```

Not sure what to change it to though.

Comment: `I read your answer` - what answer?  Could you link us to the page you're talking about?

Comment: Also, the installer (and the launcher) are pretty ridiculously *terribly* buggy. If you can't find help here, you should contact EA's support - my brother has gotten the same message when installing BF3 on his more-than-capable computer, and *(though he managed to fix this particular problem)* he still hasn't been able to play *AT ALL* yet since he bought the game three months ago, despite contacting EA literally dozens of times and being bumped up to their highest tier of support.

Comment: Where is it trying to install to?

Comment: Check the path to where you are installing it to.  Then edit your question with that answer and the space left on your hard drive please.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, download Origin, install it, and then register your game key (found in the retail box) on Origin. It will download the most recent BF3 version.